# Silverlight HtmlPage.Document.Invoke throws Failed To Invoke

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have following method having following line inside it

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showPopUp",new string[] {"Hello from Silverlight"});
```

I have one htmlhost inside the page which contains script as

```
function showPopUp(msg){
    alert(msg);
}
```

Whenever Invoke is getting called it throws exception saying Failed to invoke : showPopUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your `showPopUp` function into the .aspx page or set .html page as start page.